# How do I install the ath5k driver?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, ath5k

I'm trying to install the ath5k driver in Maverick, but the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/Fixes#Wireless don't work. I've tried to install (sudo apt-get install) `linux-backports-modules-intrepid-generic`, and also `linux-backports-modules-maverick-generic`, but both can't be found.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: I think , this a common problem. my friend had same problem but i was not interested coz mine was working fine. But link below might help u. it helped for him.
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath5k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it:

`sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-maverick-generic-wireless`

then I followed the instructions on the page (modprobe etc). Works like a charm, except for another question I'm starting now. (Asus EeePc Fn+F2 wrecks wireless until restart)